# How to efficiently search through object values?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is the most efficient way of searching for a value `bl` within an object nested in an array? (All the values of the object would have to be checked.)

Assume the following collection:

```
[
{
 id: 1,
 lang: {en: "blah", "it": "bla"}
},
{
 id: 2,
 lang: {en: "blt", "it": "bpax"}
},
{
 id: 3,
 lang: {en: "bt", "it": "bax"}
}
]
```

I would expect only:

```
[{
 id: 1,
 lang: {en: "blah", "it": "bla"}
},
{
 id: 2,
 lang: {en: "blt", "it": "bpax"}
}
]
```

How could I return all the items, whose at least one of the languages contains the string `bl`?
I thought of converting the object to array via `$objectToArray` and then back, but I am not sure whether that is the best approach.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can specify the path for the fields in a sub-document, for example `"lang.en"`. You can specify any conditions in filter using the dot notation on the fields.

Comment: I would like to loop through all they keys / languages without having to specify them.

Comment: Try `$objectToArray`.